# <html> wider than screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

Got a strange issue, my  tag has a greater width than my monitor, which it shouldn't. I have some JavaScript which gets the scroll offset and adjusts my background, to give it a parallax effect, but as you can see, once the background gets given an 100% width, it snaps and stretches out. You can see this by zooming out of the page, the background is larger.

[Here is the website](http://karl.uphero.com/)

Any idea what is going wrong with it? Here is my JavaScript, and view the CSS by inspecting the element. It has also gone a bit slow as well to be honest, was working nice and smooth.

```
var ismobile = /Android|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
if (!ismobile){
    window.onresize = function(event) {
        //Detect window size and make new padding
        if (window.innerWidth > 835) {
            var newPadding = parseInt(window.innerHeight)/2.8;
            newPadding = newPadding.toFixed(0);
            var limitPadding = 221;

            //Apply new padding value to header
            if (newPadding > limitPadding) {
                doc("header").style.padding = newPadding + "px 0px";
            }
        }
    }
    window.onscroll = function() {
        var speed = 0.7;
        var newPos = "100% " + (window.pageYOffset * speed) + "px";
        document.body.style.backgroundPosition = newPos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine in Chrome.

Comment: To me it's working fine in FF and Chrome. Very beautiful design by the way. Congratulations.

Comment: @knitevision not sure what you're talking about, I'm on my crappy work PC and it runs fine?

Comment: I can't work out why it has gone laggy, it was perfectly fine

Comment: @knitevision Well... laggy ? it's not laggy to me. It's pretty smooth. And I'm using an old computer, no ssd and an old Ubuntu version. Are u using Windows ? Maybe that's the problem... :D And about the unstyled file input buttons, it's not finished yet. Give the man a break. It looks really beautiful to me. If you can do better, nice. But why be so harsh ? I live in Brazil. Here the saying is "relax and let it roll" . Actually, that's not the right translation, but I don't think you're ready for the real one. :D

Comment: @MartynBall it's not laggy. Don't listen to her.

Comment: To be honest it is being laggy on my gaming machine when scrolling, not too sure why :S but thanks

Comment: Ah it's working fine again now, some styles are making it lag for some reason :S

Answer (score 0):

Add the overflow property to your body tag...

```
body {overflow-X: hidden;}
```